# Uninstall PowerShell 2

Tags: windows-7, windows, powershell, uninstall, control-panel

I have recently installed PowerShell 6:

http://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases

However I noticed that PowerShell now installs to:

```
C:\Program Files\PowerShell
```

While I am still left with version 2 here:

```
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell
```

I would like to remove this older version if possible. I checked these:

1. Programs and Features
2. Installed Updates
3. Windows Features

but did not see an option for PowerShell.

Comment: PowerShell 6.0 is only a subset, removing PowerShell, will break more then you think (far to many to list in a comment), at least some of those things are not compatible with PowerShell 6.  PowerShell 6 is designed to be installed along with PowerShell 2/3/4/5

Comment: Oh, and to add one more thing there is no systemic reason to remove v2. v2 and v6 will live side-by-side just fine.

Comment: Well, first of all, v6 does not provide anywhere near the capabilities of any other version. Including v1. Second, you right now have scheduled tasks and there are installs that require there be some version of powershell in C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell. So while I cannot give you a reason why two versions should be kept, there are plenty of reasons not to remove the windows specific version from your windows machine.

Comment: Here is a link that explains that PS is an integral part of the OS https://www.petri.com/how-to-uninstall-windows-powershell That is referring to the ***Windows Specific*** versions that are based on the .Net Framework. Not the cross platform version (v6) that is built on .Net Core. If you want one version of powershell and you want the latest version then upgrade to 5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was a little hesitant to post an answer since some of this will be my opinion. What is not opinion is that as of Windows 7 (Server 2008 R2) Powershell is an integral component of the operating system. Currently there are essentially two simultaneous development tracks for Powershell. There is the windows specific version which has a most recent version number of 5.1 and there is a cross platform version which is version 6. Powershell 5 is not planned to receive any further feature updates but will continue to get patched. Powershell 6 is the way that Microsoft plans to move forward.

Now we get to the opinion part. Right now in the work that I do at least powershell 6 is lacking. There are cmdlets that exist in 5 that either don't exist in 6 or the modules that they are in are not compatible with 5. So for me ( and in my opinion for many day to day admin tasks) powershell 6 is not currently a valid option.

To answer your question directly, you cannot have ***just*** powershell v6 on a windows machine. You must still have one of the windows specific versions. So, if yoou want just one version and you want the latest and greatest I would suggest removing v6 and installing v5.1.

References:

[How To Uninstall Windows Powershell](https://www.petri.com/how-to-uninstall-windows-powershell)

[Powershell 6 Roadmap](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/07/14/powershell-6-0-roadmap-coreclr-backwards-compatibility-and-more/)

Comment: Excellent answer. Microsoft should never have called v6 PowerShell. It is basically "DotNETCore with an integrated specialized minimal version of PowerShell". It has really NOTHING to do with the regular Powershell 2, 3, 4 and 5.

Comment: Well I do applaud the direction that they are going and the work that they have done so far but it is a little confusing to people coming at powershell for the first time.

Comment: I agree they are on the right track and that is nice. But they really should have given somewhat more thought to the naming of their products. It is really confusing now.

Comment: great answer - would you be willing to give an example in the answer of one of the cmdlet that is missing/incompatible

Comment: Well, the ActiveDirectory module is not compatible and I use it pretty much every day.

Comment: And just to be clear it doesn't really ***need*** to be compatible because Windows Powershell is always right there for me to use.